# How to print else only IF f1 is a match

Tags: python, if-statement

The below RegEx is currently working fine. It will return IF f1 and either f2 or f3 have a match.

I need help figuring out how to print else only IF f1 is a match e.g. print("What city and what month?)

````
import re

string = ['I am looking to rent a home in Los Angeles']

for s in string:
    f1 = re.findall(r'(.{0,50}\b(home|house|condo)\b.{0,50})',s, re.IGNORECASE)
    if f1:

        f2 = re.findall(r'(.{0,50}\b(los angeles|la)\b.{0,50})',f1[0][0], re.IGNORECASE)
        if f2:
            print("For what month?")

        f3 = re.findall(r'(.{0,50}\b(june|july|august)\b.{0,50})',f1[0][0], re.IGNORECASE)
        if f3:
            print("For what city?")```
````

Comment: You seem to be asking a question about how to structure your `if..elif` blocks. What does this have to do with regex?

Comment: You could evaluate `f2` and `f3` first, and then do `if f2: print("month?"); elif f3: print("city?"); else: print("month and city?")`

Comment: Thank you I tried your suggestion, the problem with it is if there are matches with f2 and f3 it prints the else.

also, If I was to add more IFs, the same problem would happen.

I'm looking for a way to print only if f1 happens without f2 or f3

Comment: Ok I believe I got it to work by using (if not f2 and not f3:)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After you are sure `f1` matches, collect `f2` and `f3` matches. Then check if `f2` or `f3` matched, otherwise, do `f1` block:

```py
import re
 
string = ['I am looking to rent a home in Los Angeles']
 
for s in string:
    f1 = re.search(r'.{0,50}\b(home|house|condo)\b.{0,50}',s, re.IGNORECASE)
    if f1:
        f2 = re.findall(r'(.{0,50}\b(los angeles|la)\b.{0,50})', f1.group(), re.IGNORECASE)
        f3 = re.findall(r'(.{0,50}\b(june|july|august)\b.{0,50})', f1.group(), re.IGNORECASE)
        if f2:
            print("For what month?")
        elif f3:
            print("For what city?")
        else:
            print("Only f1 fired, not f2 and f3")
    else:
        print("No f1!")
```

Comment: Thanks! Curious as to why you used search in f1 and findall for f2 and f3? I think I'd like to find all occurrences of the words in f1, would this be findall or search to achieve that?

Comment: @Izzy I think you want to check if there is  a match first. `re.search` fits best here. If you need all matches, keep using `f1 = re.findall(r'.{0,50}\b(home|house|condo)\b.{0,50}',s, re.IGNORECASE)` + `if len(f1) > 0:`

Comment: @Izzy Did it work? What is wrong with the answer?

Comment: Hi I ended up using if f1 and not f2 and not f3:

Comment: @Izzy But why minus?